# How to test webpages which are available only after signin?

Tags: security, wapiti

I am testing my company's webpages using free vulnerability assessment tools like wapiti and nikto.

The problem is that I have to test the webpages which are accessible to a user after they sign up and the tools don't have the capability to do that.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: You could log in manually and then copy the authentication cookie and set it in nikto. See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/184943/235964. That said, an automated scanner cannot catch everything. Maybe you should hire a professional pentester.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your cmdline this...

```
-a username%password --auth-method post
```